# Why is my Mapbox WMTS blurry when loaded into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wmts

I have added in a mapbox WMTS layer into QGIS. However, when loaded into QGIS the quality is poor, with everything being blurry. Do you know why it does this and how I can fix this problem?

I have copied a screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is likely served using the projection `EPSG:3857` and your project is likely using a different projection, so the images are re-projected - and therefore distorted.

Try changing the project projection by clicking on it in the lower right of the QGIS window

[image]

Comment: Yes probably this, I had the same problem before and took me a while to figure it out!

Comment: Thank you JGH, I was on British National Grid